# A question Riemann's mapping theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

Like in Riemann's mapping theorem, we have a conformal mapping $f:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{D}$ (so $f$ is bijective and holomorphic), where $\mathbb{D}=\{|z|<1,\ z \in\mathbb{C}\}$ is the set of the open unit disks.

Why does it follow from Liouville's theorem, that $\Omega$ is not the whole $\mathbb{C}$, so $\Omega \neq \mathbb{C}$?

Liouville's theorem states that if $f$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}$ and bounded, the $f$ is constant.

I really don't see how this determines $\Omega \neq \mathbb{C}$.

It would be so nice, if someone could walk me through this.

Thank you for your time,

Chris

Comment: Well, $\mathbb{D}$ is bounded. If the image of $f$ is in there, $f$ is bounded....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\Omega=\Bbb C$, since $f$ gets it's values in the unit disk, it's a bounded function. So it can't be bijective.

Note that Liouville theorem doesn't work if the open set is not $\Bbb C$. For example, when $\Omega$ is missing a ball $B(z_0,r)$, the map $f(z):=\frac 1{z-z_0}$ is bounded, holomorphic but not constant.

Comment: Ahh, the bijective property does not uphold, I see.

Comment: You probably mean $\Omega$ is _missing_ a ball $B(z_0,r)$.

Comment: @FanZheng You are right. Fixed now.